# Is Lottie Animation Support target framework 9.0?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have developed an app using target framework 9.0 and want to add Lottie animation but it's not working, when use namespace "using Lottie.Forms.Droid" its showing error and "AnimationViewRenderer.Init();" is also showing error but when I developed with target version 10.0 it's working. so I want to know can I use Lottie animation in framework 9.0 or below, if possible then how can I use please suggest me. I have already installed the required nuget packages.

my code is :
<forms:AnimationView
x:Name="animationView"

```
                Animation="18168-stay-safe-stay-home.json" 
                Loop="True" 
                AutoPlay="True"
       
                HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest stable version of the plugin is 3.1.2 , which requires framework 10.0 or higher . So if you do want to build it in 9.0 or before , you could install an older version (like 3.0.x ).

[image]